# Remove User Login from Event registration

Tags: civievent

I am creating an event for my organization and its showing the enter a username 
 as require. I want to remove this as this is a public event and it complecate things for people. I went and found where to go to allow anonymous user to register and did the anonymous role change on the dupral access but still Im getting the username thing.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to turn off the setting for profile that you have used in Event registration.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep